# Should I make all API calls with redux, or should I keep them simply in components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

I am new at using react/redux. I just started working on a react project, but I don't really know which one do I choose when when it comes to making API calls. Should I do all of API calls with redux or are there cases in which I can handle them using components?

Answer (score 3):

Choosing either one has its own merit. If you want the data from API in global state or for any further use you may need to choose to do your calls in redux.
If the interaction is very less and data is not used any further you can opt to do calls in component

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of redux the best practice would be to make you API calls directly in the "actions" of Redux.
You'll be able to find more information on this page: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

There is also another thread with a really good answer on how to make a proper API call with Redux:
[How to properly make REST calls from ReactJS + Redux application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728884/how-to-properly-make-rest-calls-from-reactjs-redux-application)